# C - How to receive from the serial port for the device side (z1 mote)

Tags: msp430, contiki

I am trying to communicate with a z1 mote that is connected to my PC directly by using `pyserial`. What I am looking to do is to write to the mote, and upon receiving the command, the mote should reply the current reading for temperature, for example.

Python side can be something like this (iinm)

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(0)  
ser.write("hello")      # the mote will receive the message and do something
```

but  I have no clue how to receive the message in the z1 mote side that uses C. Is there a special method to receive the commands or do I have to create my own?

Any tips and hints are a greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to just receive newline-terminated strings, Contiki already has functionality for that. Just wait for `serial_line_event_message` event in your protothread's loop:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "dev/serial-line.h"

PROCESS(main_process, "main process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&main_process);

PROCESS_THREAD(main_process, ev, data)
{
    PROCESS_BEGIN();
    for(;;) {
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT();

        if (ev == serial_line_event_message && data != NULL) {
           printf("got input string: '%s'\n", (const char *) data);
        }
    }
    PROCESS_END();
}
```

If on the other hand you want to customize the reception (e.g. to allow binary data, or to use custom framing, or to include checksums) you need to handle the input at the level of individual characters. Define and set a UART callback on the right UART (on the Z1 platform USB is connected to UART 0, but the number and the exact name of the function are platform-dependent). An example serial input handler function:

```
static int serial_input_byte(unsigned char c)
{
    printf("got input byte: %d ('%c')\n", c, c);
}
```

And then put this in your initialization code:

```
uart0_set_input(serial_input_byte);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I was trying to implement the given solution above but there seems to be a problem. I presume that it is because I have another python code that periodically reads from the same serial port that I need to write to. So when I implement the solution above with the other code (the one that writes), it seems that it stops the connection of the first (the one that reads) and I stop getting any input from the z1 mote. They basically clash. Does it mean that I need to implement multi threading or what can I do to fix this?

Comment: @AhmedAl-haddad No, you do not need multithreading. You need to show you code for us to understand where the problem is. But for that you should open another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222823/clash-of-connection-between-serial-port-read-and-write-codes I put the other question here. I will verify this again hopefully after the other problem is solved.

Comment: I fixed the problem I had with the clash of the connections by using multithreading. However, when I implemented your method, I didn't get anything from the z1 mote (the first one where it is supposed to printf the string). I am using the unicast-receiver.c code and I just added the if statement as shown.

Comment: I just tried the byte method and it worked. At least I can now send a signal to trigger a function in the z1 mote. Thank you sir.

Comment: @kfx I +1 because the second approach seems to be the only solution, including Contiki docs that works. If you are still in the game, I would appreciate an elaboration to the first method. `PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT()` does does not receive any event when I write to the USB.